# Set velocity limit for Pilz Planner

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

i have an universal robot ur5e and can control it with ros+moveit. I use ompl or chomp for planning.

Now i want to try the Pilz planner, where problems begin. I install the Pilz planner package and copy the pilz_command_planner_planning_pipeline.launch.xml file in my launch directory. I can launch moveit with the pilz_command_pipeline, but while starting the error

```
Exception while loading move_group capability 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService': MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type move_group::MoveGroupExecuteService as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

appears. But at the end of booting i see:

```
[ INFO] [1625746415.465549752]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin pilz::CommandPlanner
[ INFO] [1625746415.465605026]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!
```

Testing it with RViz, choosing PTP planner i got the error:

```
[ERROR] [1625746966.020478861]: velocity limit not set for group endeffector
[ERROR] [1625746966.020622564]: Exception caught: 'velocity limit not set for group endeffector'
```

Can anybody help me? I dont know where i can set the velocity limit. Changing the velocity in RViz doesn't help.
In future i want to use python for control the robot using a script like [this](https://github.com/PilzDE/pilz_tutorials/blob/master/pilz_robots_tutorials/pilz_tutorial_3/pilz_tutorial/scripts/myFirstApplication.py). But this doesn't work at all right now.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382031/set-velocity-limit-for-pilz-planner/) by [anonymous74883](https://answers.ros.org/users/74883/anonymous74883/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitsai](https://answers.ros.org/users/82290/pitsai/) on 2021-08-25**:
Hello,
Have you solved the problem yet? Because I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem a few days ago, I solved it by modifying the **joint_limits.yaml** file inside of your *_movit_config/config package. Make sure that **has_velocity_limits** and **has_acceleration_limits** are **true**, here is a code snippet.

```
 joint_limits:
     elbow_joint:
         has_velocity_limits: true
         max_velocity: 3.15
         has_acceleration_limits: true
         max_acceleration: 3
```

---

Originally posted by [oscardev](https://answers.ros.org/users/82665/oscardev/) with karma: 26 on 2021-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0